# Uncaught TypeError: j is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is giving error of Uncaught TypeError: j is not a function

Error is showing on this line

```
j("#yt_left #layered-navigation .block.block-layered-nav .block-content").toggle();
```

Please check what is wrong in this

```
<script>
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
if(j(window).width()<'760') {
  j("#yt_left #layered-navigation .block.block-layered-nav .block-content").hide();
  j("#yt_left #layered-navigation .block.block-layered-nav .block-title").css({"cursor":"pointer"});
  j("#yt_left #layered-navigation .block.block-layered-nav .block-title").click(function() {
    j("#yt_left #layered-navigation .block.block-layered-nav .block-content").toggle();
    j("#yt_left #layered-navigation .block.block-layered-nav .block-title").toggleClass("minimize");
    j("#yt_left #layered-navigation").toggleClass("active");
    j(".sort-by-wrap").toggleClass("hide");
  });

  j("#yt_left #layered-navigation .block.block-layered-nav .block-content dl dd").hide();
  j("#yt_left #layered-navigation .block.block-layered-nav .block-content dl dt").css({"cursor":"pointer"});
  j("#yt_left #layered-navigation .block.block-layered-nav .block-content dl dt").click(function() {
    j(this).next().toggle();
    j(this).toggleClass("minimize");
  });

  j(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if (j(this).scrollTop() > 750) {
      j("#layered-navigation").css({"position":"fixed","top":"0px","left":"0px","z-index":"9999","background-color":"white"});
      j(".sort-by-wrap").css({"position":"fixed","top":"3px","right":"0px","z-index":"9999","background-color":"white"});
    } else {
      j("#layered-navigation").css({"position":"unset"});
      j(".sort-by-wrap").css({"position":"unset"});
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: `var j = jQuery.noConflict(true);` ==> [**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)!

Comment: This is also not working, Please check http://prntscr.com/ekp5t5

Comment: `j` is not a good name as it's commonly used in loops thus it might get overrided without noticing!

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim, I changed variable name and it is working fine now!
Thanks once again

Comment: You're welcome! You got rid of `$` because of conflict then you got yourself in another conflict!

Comment: For such important static assignments, you have to use `const` instead of `var`. Then you would have noticed, that somewhere else in your code, `j` get's overridden.

Comment: Christoph, You are asking me to use const?